# Laravel relationships orderBy

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a simple belongsToMany relationship in model OrderProduct:

```
public function statuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderProductStatusName::class, 'order_product_statuses')
        ->withPivot('created_at');
}
```

I want to have all statuses for one product, but I want them to orderBy by pivot table on created_at. 
I was trying to do like this:

```
$orderProduct = OrderProduct::find($productId);

$statuses = $orderProduct->statuses->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'DESC');
```

But i have error 500 that method orderBy doesn't exist. How can I do this?

Comment: `statuses` would be a collection, which uses `sort` and `sortBy` instead of Eloquent's `orderBy`

Comment: I tryed as You suggested but still error 500 :(                                       
 $status = $orderProduct->statuses->sortBy('pivot_created_at', 'DESC');

Comment: Try `sortByDesc` instead. Whenever you get an error 500, always look at the error logs to find out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relations in laravel can be used as property or method. If relations used as property then returns a collection. if used as methods then returns query builder object and you can chain methods like orderBy. So in this case you should use the below code :

```
$statuses = $orderProduct->statuses()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for a very useful tip!! :)